# How can I call a PL/SQL procedure without specifying a variable to hold its OUT parameter?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I'd like to call a PL/SQL stored procedure that has an OUT parameter specified, but I don't care about the return value.  I just care that the procedure executed successfully, i.e. no exceptions thrown.

Do I have to define a dummy variable in my calling PL/SQL block to receive the out parameter even though I don't want it?  It clutters up my calling code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you'll have to define a dummy variable.

Or write a wrapper proc that ignores the variable you don't care about?

Comment: @cagcowboy I'll hold off on writing the wrapper unless I have this issue repeatedly for the same function.

Answer (score -1):

Use sys_cursor to retrieve all the columns inside the procedure..

Comment: Sorry but this in no way addresses the question.  A harder man would have downvoted it.