# Not passing an OUT parameter in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

So I have this interesting situation.  I have a PL/SQL procedure where I pass two IN parameters and two OUT parameters:

```
PROCEDURE p_merge_catalog(p_merge_from_code VARCHAR2,
                          p_merge_to_code   VARCHAR2,
                          msg_type_out      OUT VARCHAR2,
                          msg_out           OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
.
.
```

My conundrum is I'm using a job submission/scheduler program to call the procedure that does not seem to deal with OUT variables.  I'm not able to bind variables to the OUT parameters; it only passes values.  Is there a way to call this procedure without specifying an OUT parameter?  Or maybe trick it and use some kind of hidden variable?

Comment: Can you create a stored procedure that calls this proc with ignored out params, and call the former from your scheduler?

Comment: [How can I call a PL/SQL procedure without specifying a variable to hold its OUT parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421096/how-can-i-call-a-pl-sql-procedure-without-specifying-a-variable-to-hold-its-out#2421109)

Comment: I thought about that, but this procedure is already in Production and would prefer to have a work-around solution.  However, I'm guessing I might have to do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not very beautiful for two `outs`, but working ;)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_merge_catalog_wrapper (
    p_merge_from_code    VARCHAR2,
    p_merge_to_code      VARCHAR2)
    RETURN emp%ROWTYPE
IS
    msg_type_out   VARCHAR2(2000);
    msg_out   VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN
   p_merge_catalog(p_merge_from_code, p_merge_to_code, msg_type_out, msg_out);
   
   return msg_type_out || '@' || msg_out;
END;
```

Didn't check for typos. But the mechanic should be clear :o).

If you don't need the output:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_merge_catalog_wrapper (
    p_merge_from_code    VARCHAR2,
    p_merge_to_code      VARCHAR2)
    RETURN emp%ROWTYPE
IS
    msg_type_out   VARCHAR2(2000);
    msg_out   VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN
   p_merge_catalog(p_merge_from_code, p_merge_to_code, msg_type_out, msg_out);
END;
```

Comment: Thanks!  I've decided that making a wrapper is probably the best (and only) way to do it.